# Android gallery for private photos

Tags: android, gallery, uri, photo-gallery, android-imageview

How can I use default Android gallery to display only application's photos? Basically I need to display only my application photos on gallery.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! You have to parametrize the Intent that is launching the Gallery Application: Set Action to Intent.ACTION_PICK. Set MIME type to [one of the image types](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml), or image/* . Set the data to the file to be shown's Uri.

```
Intent galleryStarter = new Intent();
galleryStarter.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
galleryStarter.setType("image/*");
galleryStarter.setData(Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShow));
context.startActivity(galleryStarter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am getting an exception called ActivityNotFoundException. 
In my application I am taking number of photos. So is there a good way to series of photos?